# How to find nearest record in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to apache spark and scala and trying to learn it by example. I've got simple set of city buses location (**line number**, **time**, **longitude**, **latitute**) :

```
9, 23/09/16 10:20, 123.3, 123.3
9, 23/09/16 10:21, 125.3, 125.3
```

After few transformations, I obtained a RDD of objects :

```
class BusPosition(val line: String, val time: DateTime, val position: Point)
```

Next I want to have a `RDD` of frames, like:

```
class BusFrame(
    val line: String, val time1: DateTime, val time2: DateTime,
    val position1: Point, val position2: Point)
```

Each frame will join two closest in time records. Does anyone know how to create such set and find closest neighbor? I've searched but couldn't find suitable answer.

Comment: Some options: a) repartition, sort partitions and perform linear scan, b) use window functions with lag / lead.

Comment: Thank, but not fully got it. Could you give me some simple code example ?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways you can approach this problem. First lets adjust your classes for a better interoperability with Spark SQL:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

case class Point(longitude: Double, latitute: Double)
case class BusPosition(line: String, time: Timestamp, position: Point)

case class BusFrame(
  line: String, time1: Timestamp, time2: Timestamp,
  position1: Point, position2: Point)

val data = Seq(
  BusPosition(
    "9", Timestamp.valueOf("2016-09-23 10:20:00"), Point(123.3, 123.3)),
  BusPosition(
    "9", Timestamp.valueOf("2016-09-23 10:21:00"), Point(125.3, 125.3)),
  BusPosition(
    "7", Timestamp.valueOf("2015-08-01 00:20:12"), Point(123.9, 122.9)),
  BusPosition(
    "7", Timestamp.valueOf("2015-08-01 00:00:22"), Point(124.0, 122.6))
).toDS()
```

1. Window functions:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

   val w = Window.partitionBy("line").orderBy("time1")

   val time2 = lag($"time1", 1).over(w).alias("time2")
   val position2 = lag($"position1", 1).over(w).alias("position2")

   data.toDF("line", "time1", "position1")
     .select($"*", time2, position2)
     .na.drop(Array("time2", "position2"))
     .as[BusFrame]
   ```
2. Sliding window:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

   data.orderBy("line", "time").rdd.sliding(2).collect {
     case Array(BusPosition(l1, t1, p1), BusPosition(l2, t2, p2)) if l1 == l2 =>
       BusFrame(...)
   }
   ```
3. Custom partitioner and ordering

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.Partitioner
   import scala.math.Ordering

   class LineTimestampPartitioner(n: Int) extends Partitioner {
     def numPartitions: Int = n
     def getPartition(key: Any): Int = ??? // Partition based on line
   }

   // Order by line first, timestamp second
   implicit val lineTimestampOrd: Ordering[(String, java.sql.Timestamp)] = ???

   data.rdd
     .keyBy(bp => (bp.line, bp.time))
     .repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new LineTimestampPartitioner(n))
     .values
     .mapPartitions(_.sliding(2).collect {
       ???  // Like for mllib sliding
     })
   ```